# Got as response data in Jmeter - window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jmeter

We are trying to load test a Facebook kind of application using AJAX. Recorded a script with the help of JMeter. The application has flow like a standard one, when you login to the application and after that you browse through some of the pages and also watch/upload any image/ video if you like to.

The problem we have is that for login request, we are not able to get the actual response through JMeter {we are getting only this much: window.location.reload()}.

While when viewing the same page through Chrome Developer Tool, we are able to view the response data coming back properly i.e. page after login.  When trying to build the script manually in JMeter/postman, we are getting the same issues. It seems that JMeter is not able to execute Javascript as it isn’t a browser.
We can't use JMeter WebDriver Sampler as number of concurrent users is high.

If anyone has faced a similar issue, please let us know the solution. Thanks.

Comment: just to be clear, "Recorded script" comes from https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html ?